# Django - upload image file and store the image

Tags: python, django

In my custom user model, I need a field to store user's photo profile. So, I set a field `photo_profile` as an `ImageField` in the model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    photo_profile = models.ImageField()


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [#fields are going to be shown here
            'photo_profile',
        ]

def register_view(request):
    title = "Register"
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    print("hello")
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active = True
        user.last_login = timezone.now()
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, 'index/index.html', {"user": user})

    context ={
        "form": form,
        "title": title,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/loginRegister.html', context)
```

Now, if I go to my register page, there will be a button to upload image.

```
`<form method="post"action="" entype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" title="{{ title }}"/>
</form>`
```

After I choose my image, the of image is shown. However, when I click submit button, the webpage is asking "the field (the one for photo) is required".

Is there an other way than using a `FileUploadForm` to solve this problem？Before I change the type of photo_profile to ImageField, a user can be created.

Thanks in advance！

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to [handle files in a form, you'll need to pass them in too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files):

```
form = RegisterForm(data=(request.POST or None), files=(request.FILES or None))
```

Comment: however, still the same result. Sorry

Comment: You also have a typo -- it should be `enctype`, not `entype`.